# HttpSecurity With Spring, differentiate urls permission

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

I would like that for every url that is not under path `/cobrands` and `/fdt` a request for password. If I'm asking for example for `/fdt/name` I should not be asked for the http authentication.

```java
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 /** code **/

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint()).and()
                .authorizeUrls()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("wf_cobrand_lettura", "wf_cobrand_fdt")
                .antMatchers("/cobrands/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/fdt/*").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matchers are processed in order, so your

```
.antMatchers("/**")
```

catches all requests and the two remaining matchers are never evaluated.

Put it this way round:

```
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint()).and()
            .authorizeUrls()
            .antMatchers("/cobrands/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/fdt/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("wf_cobrand_lettura", "wf_cobrand_fdt")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
```